# Django rest framework: error when post() for foreign key

Tags: django, api, post, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I am trying to do simple get() post() to my database. I have existing database and I used inspectdb to generate the models.py from it. I am facing issue with setting up composite primary key for a model and a part of that keys are foreign key

The model TestCase has foreign key relation with TestSuite model. The get() to TestCase api works well. However the post fails with below error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist- packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
20.         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in is_valid
236.                 self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in run_validation
434.         value = self.to_internal_value(data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_internal_value
491.                 validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in run_validation
160.         return super(RelatedField, self).run_validation(data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/fields.py" in run_validation
536.         value = self.to_internal_value(data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/relations.py" in to_internal_value
263.             return self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
407.             (self.model._meta.object_name, num)

Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned at /dqf_api/test_case/
Exception Value: get() returned more than one TestSuite -- it returned 
2!
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser
```

The browsable api calls also fail with above error

models.py

```
class TestCase(models.Model):
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(TestSuite, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='team_name')
    suite_name = models.ForeignKey(TestSuite, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='suite_name')
    case_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    test_type = models.ForeignKey(TestCaseType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_case'
        unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name', 'case_name'),)


class TestSuite(models.Model):
    team_name = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='team_name')
    suite_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    #Additional fields

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_suite'
        unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name'),)

class TestCaseType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_case_type'

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'team'
```

views.py

```
class TestCaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = models.TestCase.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseSerializer

class TestSuiteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = models.TestSuite.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.TestSuiteSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class TestSuiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestSuite
        fields = '__all__'

class TestCaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCase
        fields = '__all__'
```

data.json

```
{
"case_name": "NA",
"description": "NA",
"run_level": 1,
"stop_on_failure": false,
"team_name": "ede",
"suite_name": "dummy",
"test_type": 1
}
```

Only one record with team_name =ede and suite_name = dummy is present in the test_suite table

I am new to Django and DRF. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add the ***full error traceback***

Comment: Updated the traceback in the question

Comment: In your `models.py` you have `Team` and `TestCaseType`. Please, provide the code of these models

Comment: @snehasalvi Can you show an example of the JSON data that causes the issue when it is posted?

Comment: Added the models and json data in the question